# Smarty assignByRef inside loop

Tags: php, smarty, pass-by-reference

I need to render some *Smarty* template for different values inside a loop (a *PHP* loop, not a *Smarty* `foreach`), in the following way (just an example):

```
$a = 0;
$b = 0;
$output = "";
$tmpl = "$a, $b";

$smarty->assignByRef('a', $a['a']);
$smarty->assignByRef('b', $b['b']);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
   ++$a;
   ++$b;

   $output .= $smarty->fetch("string:" . $tmpl);
}
```

My doubt is about `assignByRef`. The *Smarty v3* docs says:

> With the introduction of PHP5, assignByRef() is not necessary for most
>   intents and purposes. assignByRef() is useful if you want a PHP array
>   index value to be affected by its reassignment from a template.
>   Assigned object properties behave this way by default.

but I don't fully understand what does that technical note means. So, can I use `assignByRef` that way or not? or using just `assign` will produce the same output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 4 objects were passed *by value*, unless the user explicitly specified the reference by prepending ampersand: `&$variable`. For this reason, function arguments that were likely to consume a big amount of memory were passed by reference in order to optimize memory usage:

```
function f(&$huge) {
  // ...
}
```

PHP 5 variables are passed by reference, even if the user did't specify it explicitly (the ampersand character is not used). By assigning one variable to another we only create a new container (internally called `zval`) for the same data in memory. Consider this:

```
$a = new stdClass;
$b = $a;
```

The first line allocates memory for variable `$a` and an object of `stdClass`, and stores the object's identifier into the variable. The second line allocates memory for variable `$b`, stores the object's identifier into the `$b` variable, and increments an internal reference counter. The reference counter value shows how many times the object is referenced in the code. When `$b` variable is destroyed, the reference counter is decremented by one. When the value of reference counter becomes equal to zero, the object's memory is deallocated. The following code demonstrates the idea:

```
$a = new stdClass;
debug_zval_dump($a);
$b = $a;
debug_zval_dump($a);
$c = $a;
debug_zval_dump($a);
$c = null; // destroy $c
debug_zval_dump($a);
$b = null; // destroy $b
debug_zval_dump($a);
```

*Output*

```
object(stdClass)#1 (0) refcount(2){
}
object(stdClass)#1 (0) refcount(3){
}
object(stdClass)#1 (0) refcount(4){
}
object(stdClass)#1 (0) refcount(3){
}
object(stdClass)#1 (0) refcount(2){
}
```

But when a variable is modified, PHP versions 5 and 7 create a copy of the variable in order to keep the original value (variable) intact.

```
$m1 = memory_get_usage();

$a = str_repeat('a', 1 << 24);
echo number_format(memory_get_usage() - $m1), PHP_EOL;
// 16,781,408

$b = $a;
$c = $a;
echo number_format(memory_get_usage() - $m1), PHP_EOL;
// 16,781,472

$b[0] = 'x';
echo number_format(memory_get_usage() - $m1), PHP_EOL;
// 33,562,880

$c[0] = 'x';
echo number_format(memory_get_usage() - $m1), PHP_EOL;
// 50,344,288
```

The same is applied to the context of the function arguments. Thus, if a variable is supposed to be used for *read only*, there is no need for passing it by reference explicitly. The words in the Smarty documentation mean that in most cases, you pass variables to the templates, and usually do not expect the template to change them. You need to pass a variable by reference only when you really want the variable to be modified *in the template*. The same concept is applied to any function arguments in PHP 5 and newer.

Comment: Ok. Your last paragraph is the answer to my question. I knew that PHP implements a copy-on-write policy, but I didn't know that it wasn't the case in `PHP < v5.0`.

Comment: That copy-on-write policy, is also applied to array elements? I mean, if I pass an array to an object's function and it saves the array in an internal variable, and in a `for` I change some of the values on each loop (for instance, `v[i] = i`), does PHP apply a deep copy-on-write on the original array? in other words, will the object see the external changes? Because the "passed copy-on-write value" has not changed, but its contents.

Comment: @Peregring-lk, the array items are `zvals` themselves. PHP will create copies only for modified items, regardless of the scope.